# How to make new datatable using other tables

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

I want to create the new table from the other tables and send the emails. But, it keeps having errors on `sda.Fill(dt);`

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '('.
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Open'.

```
private DataTable GetData() 
{
    string connString = @"Data Source=aa.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=aa;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=aa;Password=aa";

    string query = "CREATE TABLE new_table AS(SELECT ID, Employee, Name, Open Date, Task FROM tblEmployees, tblEmployees, Stores, Stores, tblTasks)";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                comm.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = comm;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the error messages to the question.

Comment: Is this really mysql? Because if so you need to use `MySqlConnection`, `MySqlCommand`, etc, not `SqlConnection`, etc.

Comment: Why are you using a DataTable in the first place? What does email have to do with this?

Comment: I don't know if that is correct syntax for create table on mysql, but either way that won't return a result set. I don't think you want to create a table, you probably just want to select.

Comment: @Crowcoder I add it. and Oh yeah, it's not mysql.

Comment: @mason I should send the new table so I try to make a new table using DataTable to send an email.

Comment: That doesn't answer either of my questions.

Comment: ok, so correct your query. Columns with spaces need to be bracketed, eg, [Open Date]. Then remove everything up to and including the `(`. Then, determine if you need all those implicit joins.

Comment: You have an error in your connect string.  Open database with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL Server.  The Login screen will have  Server Name.  The database names you can get from the explorer in SSMS.  Make sure you connection string has both of these items correct.  You  can check the connection string at www.connectionstrings.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS (SELECT ...
```

If your new object is completely defined by a SELECT from another table, you want `CREATE VIEW`, not `CREATE TABLE`.  And there should be no parentheses.  And as @babak-nafias said, there must be no space in the column names - or they should be quoted with "" quotes or [] brackets.

```
CREATE VIEW new_view AS SELECT ID, Employee, Name, Open Date, Task FROM tblEmployees, tblEmployees, Stores, Stores, tblTasks;
```

Finally - if you are selecting all those tables -- tblEmployee selected twice! -- with no `JOIN` relations or even `WHERE` clauses, you are going to get:

- huge numbers of multiple identical rows
- ambiguity errors when it doesn't know which table to get Name from

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a column name with a space in it. Change `Open Date` to `[Open Date]` and your query should work.

You are also missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Good catch! and need to add the closing parenthesis or just remove CREATE TABLE new_table AS(

Answer (score 0):

The error message is referring to an in correct sql syntax you have in your query. Unless there is a particular reason, you could remove the first part of your query and make that:

`string query = "SELECT ID, Employee, Name, [Open Date], Task FROM tblEmployees, tblEmployees, Stores, Stores, tblTasks";`

(Thanks to Babak Naffas for catching that space in column name)

That should resolve the `SqlException`.

Also, `DataTable` doesn't implement `IDisposable` so why are you using `Using` statement? You could remove that `Using` statement too

```
using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
{
    comm.Connection = con;
    sda.SelectCommand = comm;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```